# Recursively chmod/chown/chgrp all files and folder within a directory

Tags: php, recursion, cron, file-permissions, chmod

I am working on a site which builds other sites.  Some if it I use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to create the files and directories, other times I'm building XML files in php and using [DOMDocument::save](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) to save them.  The end result is a root folder with all sorts of messed up permissions.  I've beening modding files and folders as I go, which words to some extent, but I'm particularly  having trouble when it comes to using `copy()`.

(This is where I'm at so far http://pastebin.com/SBE8vtFX, attn: `function modPath($path)`)

I want to take a different approach and recursively **chmod/chown/chgrp** all the files and folders within my document root to my specifications *at once*.

Take for example the document root

```
/home/mysite/public_html
```

and within `public_html` I have

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 mysite mysite  348 Aug 31 10:49 index.php
d--------x  5 root   root   4096 Aug 30 10:21 folder1
drwxrwxrwx  2 mysite mysite 4096 Aug 30 09:41 folder2
```

---

### My question:

How can I mod **all** files within a specified directory at once?  I want to differentiate different chmod settings between directories and folders as well.  This needs to be a PHP solution.

This is as far as I can get

```
<?php

    function modAll($root) {
        
        $aPath = explode("/", $root);
        
        $user = $aPath[2];
        
        /* Some sort of looping through $root */ {
            
            $mod = (is_dir($thisfileorfolder) ? 0755 : 0644);
                    
            chmod($thisfileorfolder, $mod);
            chown($thisfileorfolder, $user);
            chgrp($thisfileorfolder, $user);
        }
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: If the PHP calling a bash command (`exec`, `system`), does it considered as a PHP solution?

Comment: I'm using a cron job to call the PHP file (as root user) so if that's possible, then sure.

Comment: chown, chmod and chgrp are supporting recursive, maybe this don't even require PHP, use `find` better?

Comment: Only the superuser may change the owner of a file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be helpful. 
EDITED: some syntax errors corrected

```
    function fsmodify($obj) {
       $chunks = explode('/', $obj);
       chmod($obj, is_dir($obj) ? 0755 : 0644);
       chown($obj, $chunks[2]);
       chgrp($obj, $chunks[2]);
    }


    function fsmodifyr($dir) 
    {
       if($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {        
           foreach($objs as $obj) {
               fsmodify($obj);
               if(is_dir($obj)) fsmodifyr($obj);
           }
       }

       return fsmodify($dir);
    }
```

Comment: so `fsmodifyr('/path/to/dir/');` ?

Comment: it works?, i use that implementation for recursive delete, i am sure that works

Comment: This is drool worthy... Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can perform a [system](https://www.php.net/manual/function.system.php) call

```
system("/bin/chmod -R $mod $root");
system("/bin/chown -R $user $root");
system("/bin/chgrp -R $user $root");
```

of course you use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd()
in order to avoid executing arbitrary commands

Comment: 1) how can I specify different permissions for files vs folders, 2) `/bin/chmod: invalid mode: `493' Try `/bin/chmod --help' for more information.`

Comment: You cannot I guess back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0):

```
system("/bin/chmod -R $mod $root");
system("/usr/bin/find -type d $root -print0 | xargs -0 | /bin/chmod $moddir");
system("/bin/chown -R $user $root");
system("/bin/chgrp -R $user $root");
```

Invalid mode 493 means you passed your mode as decimal. Convert to octal string first.