# change ownership of file in apache

Tags: php, apache, ownership

I am working on apache sever and generating some tmpdir using follwoing code.

```
$tmpdatadir = "/home/user/tmpdata/".$id."/";

if (mkdir($tmpdatadir)) {
        /* do something */

}
```

dir created:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data     www-data        4096 Aug 30 17:16 147257020639481
```

but when i try to write some data using

```
exec ("cat file.txt >". $tmpdatadir."sample.txt")
```

i get following error message.

permission denied. As i copy file as user:user so how can i change permision of directory. I found chown does this but i am not sure how can i change ownership of whole directory.

Comment: Use `print shell_exec('whoami');` to see, witch user is running your `cat` line. If it is not (and i say it will not) `www-data` then thats the problem. You have to change the rights of the folder after creating the dir.

Comment: yes it is www-data but how can i change permssion after creating dir?

Comment: [dublicate] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261566/recursively-chmod-chown-chgrp-all-files-and-folder-within-a-directory

Comment: but i checked for chown user must be superuser but it need password to be entered.  System("chown -R ".$user.":".$user." myfolder");

Comment: I thing you should do it completly with PHP (and the php functions) , not create the folder with PHP and then do the rest via `system()`*command line* , do it fully with PHP. Because you are the right user `www-data` at this point and can change perms from there.

Comment: Or do all only with *command line* and create the directory in the first place with: `system('mdir /folder/')`

Comment: Im out, have fun:)

Comment: i just checked it needs to be superuser for changing permission so i must use system("sudo chown -R ".$user.":".$user." ".$tmpdatadir); but i cannot enter password that time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122369/discussion-between-ankit-kumar-and-justonundermillions).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please review the permissions for `www-data` folder with `ls /lrt`, is that way you can see if your user is able to write on the file.

Then, you can use the command: `chmod 666 www-data` to change the permission of the file to read and write for all users, in [this link](https://chmod-calculator.com/) you can find the syntax for `chmod` command and a useful calculator if you want limit other users.
Also I share with you the specific functions for commands `chown` and `chmod`. See [this site](https://www.unixtutorial.org/difference-between-chmod-and-chown/).