# CronJobs failure, possibly a syntax error?

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run a cronjob (my first time ever) but it isn't working as expected.
The PHP file I'm trying to run, contains a tiny code which sends an SMS message every time it is executed.
When I open the URL to the file on my browser, it works perfectly and sends the SMS message.
But the cronjob doesn't.

Here's the command I use:

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_A_SUBDOMAIN/crontest.php`

I wrote the command using the guide cPanel provides at the exact same page you define a cronjob. So I basically think there's no syntax error there.
Needless to say I checked the timezone for the server and compared to one I set for the cronjob.

**EDIT**

Here's the code existing on the PHP file:

```
session_start();
require_once 'maincore.php'; // contains some funtions and settings
include_once INCLUDES.'SendMessage.php'; // contains required functions for sending the SMS.
//
and some other codes here to eventually send the SMS, which works flawless
//
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so, since I added that CronJob, the CPU Usage and Disk Space Usage on my hosting panel boosted to the skies. So I tried checking my error log to identify the cause.

Now let me add some more information. The **maincore.php** file which I mentioned, contains some functions and also the following code:

```
$folder_level = "";
while (!file_exists($folder_level."config.php")) { $folder_level .= "../"; }
require_once $folder_level."config.php";
define("BASEDIR", $folder_level);
```

There are 2 things to point out here:

1. **config.php** file contains database information like username, password, etc.
2. That code tries to find the **config.php** file and include it. In case it doesn't find the file, it will go back 1 folder each time and tries finding the file again in case the **maincore.php** was misplaced.

As it turned out, the code I just mentioned, causes an endless loop which refers to `file_exists` function.

The error log contains lots of the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../.. in /home/MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_A_SUBDOMAIN/maincore.php

PHP Warning:  file_exists(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (4096): ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../ in /home/MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_A_SUBDOMAIN/maincore.php
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you replace `MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_A_SUBDOMAIN` with actual values?

Comment: @Justinas Yes of course :)

Comment: Is your code independent from web context? Like using `_GET`, sessions, index file?

Comment: @Justinas I edited the question and added the codes on the PHP file as well.

Comment: Try adding `2>/home/MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_A_SUBDOMAIN/errors.log` to see if any errors happends

Comment: @Justinas If you wouldn't mind, please read the update on the original post.

Comment: So your `while (!file_exists($folder_level."config.php"))` never finds file. Ensure it exists. Also put initial `$folder_level` to be `__DIR__ . '/'` to ensure that you start at current file location. Better get rid of that "find where config is" and use absolute paths via `__DIR__`, `dirname(__DIR__)` etc.

Comment: @Justinas It's getting stranger each time I try something. So, this time, I removed all codes from the file and merely put these 2 lines of code: `fopen('mytestfile1.html', 'w');` and `fopen(__DIR__ . '/'.'mytestfile2.html', 'w');` I used 2 versions of the code to ensure the current directory will be used. But none of the files were created! Needless to say that I used the exact same Cron Job command, and that files are created when I write the exact url on my browser and open the file manually.

Comment: Put `__DIR__` everywhere where you refer to file. Also ensure that your PHP script, that possible is running under different user than when accessing through web, has all permissions to create/read files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261566/recursively-chmod-chown-chgrp-all-files-and-folder-within-a-directory